# How to convert UTC time into IST Time in mongoDB schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

i am placing `date.now()` in default section in database schema. but i get only UST time in mongodb. i need IST time. how to convert it?
my code

```
created at:
{
type:Date,
default:Date.now()
}
```

Comment: Date values in MongoDB are always any only stored as UTC time. Usually the client application is responsible to display it in local time.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert in your code (python / java) and then store it in your DB. Best practice would be to store your data as UTC inside your DB and then handle conversion at the app layer.